# Deciding when to vote for team approval when people are disagreeing.

Tags: the-resistance

Really - the team approval phase is the only part where people's agreement/disagreement about who are the spies/etc have substance.

What commonly happens is that two of three people will be arguing about something, and it will be a bit of a stalemate, and someone else saying 'Just vote!'.

What should happen here? How do you decide when the vote should happen, or whether to keep arguing?

Comment: Arguing, if I recall, is actually outside of the game mechanics. The player who's turn it is nominates people and once he/she has done so, everyone votes. Any attempt to get a consensus before voting is just player banter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the leader chooses a team, the mechanics say it's time to vote. If people aren't respecting that and keep arguing anyway, the leader should overrule them and force the issue.

Note that if the leader tries to rush through a vote "too quickly", the team is likely to be rejected and the leader likely to fall under suspicion, so this is self-policing.

Comment: What about if the leader is one of the people that is argueing, and he's apparently outvoted? He won't want to proceed with the vote knowing that it will be shut down.

Comment: House rule the same way you would houserule any other game where someone takes too long or refuses to take their turn. That problem isn't Resistance-specific.

Comment: "He won't want to proceed with the vote knowing that it will be shut down" - that's a rather *naive* mindset, no? (@dwjohnston) There are several instances wherein a leader would intentionally put together a team that they have no intention of approving (though they might not say as much at the time!)...

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 You devious so and so you. I might ask a new question asking why.

Comment: Mwahahaha! Let's see if I can come up with a few examples...

Comment: 1) I am Merlin (in the **Avalon** version of the game), and know most (if not all) of the spies/traitors. Since they only need identify me to secure a win, I must do things to throw them off the trail, like forming a team with spies on it.

Comment: 2) As a spy, I could put together a "decent" team (according to what popular opinion seems to be on who is loyal, etc) and then vote either way. I could reject this team and claim [whatever], when my real motive was to advance the "reject five teams in a row and the spies win" objective.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 OP did go ask it as a separate question - http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/16723/why-might-a-leader-propose-a-team-they-dont-plan-to-approve

Comment: @dwjohnston Presumably the player wants the game to continue though.